# Error Flushing Chunks to S3: "dial tcp: lookup chunks.<endpoint>: no such host

Tags: grafana-loki, grafana-templating, promtail

I have successfully set up Loki and Promtail on my EKS cluster, and I observe that logs are being stored in the specified S3 bucket. However, I'm facing an issue with the **loki-write-0** pod. Despite logs being stored, the pod consistently logs an error: **### "failed to flush chunks: store put chunk: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Put "https://chunks./self-monitoring/88b42ba8e2d3f407/18bf041b658%3A18bf07c4e66%3A72deb4b2": dial tcp: lookup chunks.: no such host"**. This is puzzling because the logs do get stored in the **af-south-1-dev-loki-chunks-bucket**. I'm unsure what's causing this error or how to resolve it, given that log storage in S3 seems to be functioning. Any insights into why this error might be occurring or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

I am also sharing my configuration file for Loki. I would appreciate it if someone could review it to see if there are any misconfigurations or improvements that I can make. Please note that sensitive information has been redacted for security purposes.

[image]